# Thymleaf, value of a variable set to an attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this:

```
 <span th:if="${colorValue =='green'}">
        <h1 color: green;  text-align:center;">
            <span th:text="${title}"></span>:
        </h1>
        </span>
```

What I would like is, to remove the span tag and set something like <h1 color: ${colorValue} text-align:center;">
That means setting color attribute directly by colorValue.
How do I do that?

Comment: `<h1 color: green; text-align:center;">` looks nothing like valid HTML. Did you mean `<h1 style="color:green; text-align:center;">`? Or `<h1 color="green">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `<h1 color: green; text-align:center;">` looks nothing like valid HTML.

Given you wanted to set css with conditional color you can utilize [th:styleappend](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending):

```
<h1 th:styleappend="'color: ' + ${colorValue} + '; text-align:center;'">
    <span th:text="${title}"></span>:
</h1>
```

Given you wanted to set attribute "color" you can utilize [th:attr](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute):

```
<h1 th:attr="color=${colorValue}">
    <span th:text="${title}"></span>:
</h1>
```

Comment: Witaj Jakub, thank you so much. Your first suggestion solved the problem. Perfect!

Comment: You're welcome :) You may also accept my aswer since it solved your problem.